# Having trouble creating hands for multiple players

Tags: java

I've got my program to the point where it asks the user to input the number of cards as well as the number of players. I'm just looking to print out each of the players cards. ex. (Player 1: Ace of Spades, Two of Hearts. Player 2: Two of Clubs, etc..) I have got it to print out, but it seems to only print out one set of cards despite there being 2 inputted into the number of players. Here's my code.

Hand Class:

```js
public class Hand 
{
 private int handSize;   //how many cards in the hand
 private int cardsInHand;  //counter
 private Card [] hand;
 
 
 public Hand ()
 {
  hand = new Card[52];
  handSize = 5;
  cardsInHand = 0;
 }
 
 public Hand (int handSize)
 {
  hand = new Card [handSize];
  this.handSize = handSize;
  
 }

 public void addCard (Card card)
 {
  if (cardsInHand >= handSize) 
  {
   Card[] temp = new Card[hand.length*2];
   for (int i=0; i < cardsInHand; i++)
   { 
    temp[i] = hand[i];
    hand = temp;
   }
  }
  
 }
```

Deck Class:

```js
public class Deck 
{
 
 private Card [] deck;
 private int nextCard;
 
 
 public Deck()
 {
  deck = new Card[52];
        int iCardCount=0;  // Holds how many cards have been created.
        for ( int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++ ) 
        {
            for ( int face = 1; face <= 13; face++ ) 
            {
                deck[iCardCount] = new Card(iCardCount);
                iCardCount++;
            }
        }
        nextCard = 0;
 }
 
    public Card dealACard ()
 {
  if (nextCard < 52)
  {
   System.out.println( deck[nextCard++]);
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.print("\nError, out of cards." ); 
  }
  return (null);
 }
   
 public Hand dealAHand (int n)
 { 
  Hand hand = new Hand(n);
  Card deal = new Card(n);
  
 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  { 
   hand = dealACard();
  }
  return hand;
 }
```

My driver:

```html
System.out.println ("How many cards in the hand? ");
int iHand = kb.nextInt();
Hand newHand = new Hand(iHand);
System.out.println("How many players are playing? ");
int iPlayers = kb.nextInt();
Deck secondDeck = new Deck();
secondDeck.shuffle();
secondDeck.dealAHand(iHand);
```

What I get as an output:

```js
How many cards in the hand? 
5
How many players are playing? 
2
the TWO of SPADES
the ACE of HEARTS
the TEN of DIAMONDS
the QUEEN of CLUBS
the NINE of HEARTS
```

I'd like for it to print out two sets of cards as opposed to just one, but I logically can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Well, you're only calling `dealAHand` once.  Maybe you need to call it in a loop, if you want it to be called `iPlayers` times.

Comment: You really need to stop coding for a second and think about what you're doing in *terms of object oriented design*. Your code will never be good if the underlying assumptions are wrong. Get yourself a deck of cards. Set up a game. Think about how the game would be played in the absence of computers and code. Think about what objects are involved. Think about what kind of data those objects should record and what kind of behaviors they should demonstrate.

Comment: Yeah, I did that but how can I get it to where it shows Player 1, Player 2, Player 3 in the loop?  Here's how I have it in the loop. `for for (int i=0; i<=iPlayers; i++)
  {
   secondDeck.dealAHand(iHand);
   System.out.println("Player");
  }`

Comment: Yes, that looks like the right thing to be doing.  What goes wrong when you try that?

Answer (score 0):

You only have one instance of Hand and like D.Wallace says you're only calling dealAHand once.  Before you even start coding, you should work out more of the structure of your solution.